# Downloading .jpg files with different names

Tags: download, wget

I would like to download at once all .jpg files but when I downloading e.g.

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://das.familysearch.org/das/v2/dgs:005600565_000{11..32}/dist.jpg
```

I got

```
dist.jpg
dist.jpg.1
dist.jpg.2
dist.jpg.3
dist.jpg.4
dist.jpg.5
```

What I want is to download as

```
dist.jpg as 11.jpg
dist.jpg.1 as 12.jpg
...
```

I have tried with -O, see https://serverfault.com/questions/258625/using-wget-to-save-sequential-files-as-well-as-renaming-the-file-extension
but is not woking. 
My system is Mac OS X.

Comment: I would like to know the answer, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I solve the problem using `curl` instead of `wget` e.g.

```
curl -o "#1.jpg" https://das.familysearch.org/das/v2/dgs:005600565_000[11-32]/dist.jpg
```